# I misunderstand grep manual in regards to -o (only-matching)

Tags: grep

`grep` manual quote:

> **-o, --only-matching**
> Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

`matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line` means *non empty line* right?

### Update

In case comments are deleted, from Stephen's answer below:

> - Paraphrase: How about "empty strings in a line" instead "empty parts of a matching line"? –
>   Lahor
>   10 hours ago
> - I think the important label is “matched parts”; “matched strings” would work too, I’m not the right person to ask which is better. –
>   Stephen Kitt
>   59 mins ago

Comment: Just to add a tidbit here even though it's not directly related to matching empty strings. It's worth noting that `echo foo |grep -o ..` will only return `fo` and not `oo`. This is because grep consumes the results and then looks for another match; `echo food |grep -o ..` will get you `fo` and `od` but still no `oo`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It really refers to non-empty matched parts of a matching line, not non-empty lines. The *result* is that the output only contains non-empty lines, each one containing a non-empty match.

`grep -o` prints one line per match:

```
$ grep -Eo '.?' <<<"hello"
h
e
l
l
o
```

but it doesn’t output empty matches. Many regular expressions can match empty text; for example:

```
$ grep -E '.?' <<<""
```

outputs a blank line because the empty line matches. However, adding `-o` results in no output at all:

```
$ grep -Eo '.?' <<<""
```

because `-o` ignores empty matches.

Specifying that `-o` ignores empty matches means the implementers don’t need to decide what to do with zero-length matches, which would otherwise produce rather lengthy (and useless) output in many circumstances.

Comment: Hello Stephen, wouldn't the best term to use be "empty strings in a line" instead "empty parts of a matching line"?

Comment: I think the important label is “matched parts”; “matched strings” would work too, I’m not the right person to ask which is better.

Answer (score 6):

Consider these two commands:

```
grep -o '^' <<<'1a2b3c'
```

this outputs nothing since it matches the start of the line and that's empty, so it doesn't output it.

---

```
grep -o '[abc]' <<<'1a2b3c'
```

this outputs the matched (non-empty) part of the matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

```
a
b
c
```